# Skipping first action in else-parts of script?

Tags: if-statement, autohotkey

When I cast the following script, the accented lines are skipped.  Can anyone tell me why?  How can I fix this, to make a script that works correctly?

```
MsgBox, 3, , Dimensions?, Wide (yes)?  Landscape (no)?
IfMsgBox, Yes
    Send ^+{PrintScreen}
    Sleep 1500
    MouseClickDrag, left, 0, 200, 600, 400
    Sleep 1000
    Send 1
    Return
IfMsgBox, No

    //SKIPPED
    //SKIPPED
    Send ^+{PrintScreen}
    //Skipped
    //Skipped

    Sleep 1500
    MouseClickDrag, left, 0, 200, 600, 400
    Sleep 1000
    Send 1
    Return
IfMsgBox, Cancel

    //SKIPPED
    //SKIPPED
    Send ^+{PrintScreen}
    //Skipped
    //Skipped
    Sleep 1500
    MouseClickDrag, left, 0, 200, 600, 400
    Sleep 1000
    Send 1
    Return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you use Curly brackets, only the first line after an IF statement will be considdered to be part of that statement. Try this instead. B.t.w. do you realize that all 3 If's execute exactly the same code?

```
MsgBox, 3, , Dimensions?, Wide (yes)?  Landscape (no)?
IfMsgBox, Yes
{
    Send ^+{PrintScreen}
    Sleep 1500
    MouseClickDrag, left, 0, 200, 600, 400
    Sleep 1000
    Send 1
    Return
}
IfMsgBox, No
{
    Send ^+{PrintScreen}
    Sleep 1500
    MouseClickDrag, left, 0, 200, 600, 400
    Sleep 1000
    Send 1
    Return
}
IfMsgBox, Cancel
{
    Send ^+{PrintScreen}
    Sleep 1500
    MouseClickDrag, left, 0, 200, 600, 400
    Sleep 1000
    Send 1
    Return
}
```

Comment: Verified correct.  Prior to making the contents of each block the same, I checked empty else blocks.  This is a step in design done in testing when learning new languages.